# Update List from other list .NET6

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-6.0

I'm looking for an easy way to update/insert/delete items inside one list (EF) with the data from another list. Currently  I'm doing something like this:

```
public UpdateSomeList(List<Foo> foos, List<Foo> foosNew)
{
    //remove missing
    foos.RemoveAll(x => !foosNew.Select(xx => xx.Id).Contains(x.Id));

    //update existing
    var updatedCount = foosNew
        .Join(foos,
            @new => @new.Id, old => old.Id,
            (@new, old) =>
            {
                old.Value = @new.Value
                return old;
            }
        )
        .Count();

    //insert new
    var toAdd= foosNew
        .Where(x => !foos.Select(xx => xx.Id).Contains(x.Id));
    foos.AddRange(toAdd);
}
```

Is there more elegant way of doing this or I just should make an extension for this use case from my example and thats it?

Comment: Is it necessary to update the existing list rather than just replace it with the new list?

Comment: Do you need to preserve reference to the old list? Or creating a new one is an option? Do you need to update existing elements or swapping is an option? Is it actually about merging data in database? And in your current approach I highly recommend to do ` var newIds = foosNew.Select(xx => xx.Id).ToHashSet();` instead of doing that in `Where` and `RemoveAll`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay In my real code I have `PK Guid G_Id` and `int Id`. So I cannot replace them because even if Id matches Guid will be different and on saving changes new object saved to db rather then updated

Comment: @GuruStron I need to preserve my references as it is my EF entities

Comment: One quick win: replace `.Select(xx => xx.Id).Contains(x.Id)` with `.Any(xx => xx.Id == x.Id)`

Comment: @Kilas `In my real code` post the real code then. Entity Framework deals with tables, not lists. If you want to update table rows with detached objects, you don't have to *load* the data, you only need to attach the new objects in the modified state. If you want to update specific field only, EF Core or any ORM are probably the *wrong* tool. No objects are involved in this case, just keys and values. Why load an object when you actually want to execute `update table1 set field1=@value when ID=@id` ?

Comment: @Kilas `on saving changes new object saved to db` that's not how EF Core works. If  the attached object is in the `Modified` state an `UPDATE` will be issued. You can use [DbContext.UpdateRange(Object\[\])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.updaterange?view=efcore-5.0) to attach the "new" objects in the modified state

Comment: 1. @PanagiotisKanavos real code would be too complex to illustrate the issue. The use case is that I'm getting some complex Json object from external api and I'm remapping it to my Entity. The goal is to update my stored copy in db with the one from external api on demand. So I load Entity with its collections and then update them +- as shown in my example.

Comment: 2. @PanagiotisKanavos yes its not exactly how it works, but I would prefer just adding new, deleting missing and updating existing entries rather then replacing the list with the new one and then trying to figure out if state is `Added`/`Updated`/`Removed` as ef would do that with change tracker

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to use something like this:

```
public static void MergeWith<TItem, TKey>(
    this List<TItem> destination, 
    IEnumerable<TItem> newItems,
    Func<TItem, TKey> keySelector,
    Action<TItem, TItem> update)
{
    var itemsToAdd = newItems.ToDictionary(keySelector);
    destination.RemoveAll(x => !itemsToAdd.ContainsKey(keySelector(x)));
    
    foreach (TItem oldItem in destination)
    {
        TKey key = keySelector(oldItem);
        TItem newItem = itemsToAdd[key];
        itemsToAdd.Remove(key);
        update(oldItem, newItem);
    }
    
    destination.AddRange(itemsToAdd.Values);
}
```

Usage:

```
foos.MergeWith(foosNew, x => x.Id, (oldItem, newItem) =>
{
    oldItem.Value = newItem.Value;
});
```